# Pull a full object from one value

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a ticket system, and I want to make a close ticket system, that will remove the ticket from the user, so I have my mongo array looking like this

```json
{
    "tickets": [{
        "id": "cxZgqey2",
        "subject": "fdgfdgdfgfdgfd",
        "message": "gfdgfdgfdgdfg",
        "ownerEmail": "soenmtherhg@gmail.com"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "r4r-CnIC",
        "subject": "dfdsfdsfsdfdsfdsf",
        "message": "dsfdsfdfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsf",
        "ownerEmail": "soenmtherhg@gmail.com"
    }
]}
```

and I wanted to remove the entire object using only the id, how would I do this? (Using the npm module (not mongoose))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the filter function in arrays and delete it passing the relevant id for that and also you can check [loadash](https://lodash.com/).

Comment: Lodash for a simple slice/splice... "Use library xyz for this simple task"